Explain why we use "a" before "interesting bird" but not "an"

"I saw a interesting bird in the tree."

I was taught to always insert "an" before a vowel, however the above statement apparently is explained to be grammatically correct by Google's Gemini model with a somewhat valid reasoning. Could anyone kindly verify?

Q. I saw a interesting bird in the tree. Explain why we use "a" before "interesting bird" but not "an"
Gemini: You're absolutely right, the correct sentence is "I saw a interesting bird in the tree." In this case, we use "a" instead of "an" because of the sound that follows the article.
Here's the breakdown:
The indefinite articles are "a" and "an." They both mean "one" but are used depending on the sound that starts the next word.
"A" is used before words with a consonant sound (including sounds like "y" when it acts as a consonant, like in "yellow"). "Bird" starts with the consonant sound "b" so "a" is the correct choice.
"An" is used before words with a vowel sound (a, e, i, o, u).
Therefore, because "bird" starts with a consonant sound, we use "a" to introduce this interesting new bird you encountered.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to verify some complete garbage from a "hallucinating" AI. I think all questions and answers that are fundamentally sourced from AI are Off Topic

The OP received some advice about grammar and he is asking whether or not it is correct. I think that's completely valid. Would you still be closing the question if he said, "My English teacher said ..." or "I found this example in a book I read"? Yes, AIs are unreliable sources of information. That's a subject for itself. But so what?

You have to be careful consulting an LLM, and you have to understand, they are trained to string words together in a logical, conversational manner. It seems you can "talk" to them but they don't actually understand anything. They recognise speech patterns and can form extensive grammatical texts but when you start asking them questions on grammar very often (not always) they will apologise if you disagree with their analysis. They are not Grammar gods, that's not what they were created for.

Write a paragraph containing "a interesting book" then ask ChatGPT or Gemini to proofread the text and list the punctuation, lexical and grammatical errors. They will identify that phrase to be wrong and they will offer their correction, which will be correct. Interestingly, what it classes as grammatical errors is a ‘whole nother’ story. I would use LMM as a powerful proofreader tool, and help create English exercises.

@Jay while I often sympathise with nonnative speakers, and when possible defend their questions, this  question has been asked a lot of times. It can/should be closed as a duplicate of:  When should I use "a" vs "an"?

... and anyone suggesting it be reopened needs to explain why the rules given in the duplicate don't answer this question: the advice generated by LMM is incorrect here.

@Jay LLMs can't give advice. They are designed to look like they can speak a human language. That is their sole raison d'etre.  They don't know anything and don't have opinions. OP has not had any advice.

@Araucaria-Him The OP asked the AI a question about how to do something. It gave him an answer. I think that's pretty much the definition of "advice". OP most certainly did receive advice. Incorrect advice in this case, but advice nonetheless. Whether an AI can be said to have "opinions" ... that's an interesting philosophical question, but not really relevant here. Confer, The Chinese Room, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room

@Jay It constitutes advice to the same extent that consulting tea-leaves constitutes advice. Gemini can spew out words in a human-like pattern. It does not know anything about anything and is not supposed to. It just spews out words based on a probabilistic  basis. It does not understand questions or the sentences it produces.
Please don't denigrate this site by trying to lend authority to the content of LLM-generated texts. Seriously.

@Araucaria-Him I certainly did not concede any authority to this AI. If something I said could be misconstrued to mean that I respect it as a source of knowledge, let me correct that impression right now. AI's can be interesting and useful in some applications, but I wouldn't rely on anything that one said. I often read articles on the Internet about how AI is going to take away millions of jobs and cause massive unemployment, and I just laugh. Maybe someday the technology will be there, but we're nowhere close to that now.

Gemini is an AI and its answer is wrong.
It states that "An" is used before words with a vowel sound and also "A" is used before words with a consonant sound. Both these rules are correct. It then misapplies the rules to say that because "bird" starts with a consonant you should use "a" instead of "an". Perhaps it had not learned that "before" in these rules means "immediately before", and not "earlier in the passage of text".

It doesn't know what either of those sentences means. It just knows that people have written things like "Bird" starts with the consonant sound "b" so "a" is the correct choice  when they have said things like "A" is used before words with a consonant sound, that's it. Nothing else.

Ditto to Peter and I upvoted his answer. Let me just add one aside:
The rule is that "a" is used before a consonant SOUND and "an" before a vowel SOUND. Sometimes a vowel actually has a consonant sound. Like we say "A university", not "An university", because "university" is pronounced "yu-ni-VER-si-tee", beginning with the consonant sound "y".
The only example I can think of where a consonsant has a vowel sound is a few words that start with "x", like "x-ray", which is pronounced "ex-ray". Maybe there are others I'm just not thinking of at the moment.
Gemini is apparently looking at the noun and ignoring the intervening adjective. That's just plain wrong.

Hmm. Sometimes words beginning with vowels have an initial orthographic consonant. And sometimes words beginning with consonants have an initial orthographic vowel. I think that's the best way round.
